# Files/folders created by application have wrong permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, umask

I've got strange issue.
Newly created folders from Nuke (compositing software) on our network storage with my user are being created with **755** permissions. However, If I open up an console, browse the same location and **mkdir** new folder it is created with 775 mask as it should.
Storage is mounted via NFS with user account managed by LDAP server.

**Umask** is same as the one on the computer next to mine, on which there is no such issue (Nuke is being used there as well).
I'd appreciate some pointers on the matter.

Comment: Please edit question with details about your network storage (Samba? Something else?), as this can and will influence permissions. Also use `ps` to check of all subprocesses of Nuke are running as the current user.

Comment: Added some more info.
Obviously, Linux workstations (CentOS 7). We are mounting our NAS via NFS.

Comment: It's also quite possible that Nuke sets its own umask, for whatever reasons. Possibly you can configure it somewhere.